# How to Get Next or Previous Post in a Specific Tag?

Tags: tags, links, navigation, next-post-link

I'm trying to create links to the next and previous posts within a specific tag (on the post page itself), but I can't seem to find a plugin or source that does this.

I want to be able to something like this, appearing below the post.

```
get_previous_link("tagname");
get_next_link("tagname");
```

Anybody know of a way to accomplish this? Otherwise I'll have to write something myself, which is fine, but I figured I wouldn't reinvent the wheel unless I have to.

Comment: are you talking about outside of the `/tag/tagname` page?

Comment: I'm talking about on the single.php page. Will edit to make that more clear.

Answer (score 6):

[`get_adjacent_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_adjacent_post), which is used by all functions that return a (link to) the next or previous post, only has a `$in_same_cat` argument, which looks at the categories the post is in, not the tags.

You could hook into the `get_[next|previous]_post_join` to modify the join query for your call, but then it's probably easier to [copy the function](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.1/wp-includes/link-template.php#L1088), remove the category-specific code and replace it with tag-specific code. Or make it even more generic and submit it as a patch to WordPress :-)

Comment: Yeah, I found that function, was hoping somebody else had already written it =)

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for that problem? http://digwp.com/2010/04/post-navigation-outside-loop/

The code in that post works for "Archive-View Pages" & "Single-View Pages" :P

Comment: That doesn't give me specific tag links.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version of the copy/paste edit that @Jan Fabry alluded to above (definitely not the most elegant solution, but it should work):

```
/**
 * Retrieve adjacent post.
 *
 * Can either be next or previous post.
 *
 *
 * @param bool $in_same_tag Optional. Whether post should be in same category.
 * @param string $excluded_tags Optional. Excluded tags IDs.
 * @param bool $previous Optional. Whether to retrieve previous post.
 * @return mixed Post object if successful. Null if global $post is not set. Empty string if no corresponding post exists.
 */
function get_adjacent_post_by_tag($in_same_tag = false, $excluded_tags = '', $previous = true) {
    global $post, $wpdb;

    if ( empty( $post ) )
        return null;

    $current_post_date = $post->post_date;

    $join = '';
    $posts_in_ex_tags_sql = '';
    if ( $in_same_tag || !empty($excluded_tags) ) {
        $join = " INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships AS tr ON p.ID = tr.object_id INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy tt ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tt.term_taxonomy_id";

        if ( $in_same_tag ) {
            $tag_array = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID, 'post_tag', array('fields' => 'ids'));
            $join .= " AND tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND tt.term_id IN (" . implode(',', $tag_array) . ")";
        }

        $posts_in_ex_tags_sql = "AND tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag'";
        if ( !empty($excluded_tags) ) {
            $excluded_tags = array_map('intval', explode(' and ', $excluded_tags));
            if ( !empty($tag_array) ) {
                $excluded_tags = array_diff($excluded_tags, $tag_array);
                $posts_in_ex_tags_sql = '';
            }

            if ( !empty($excluded_tags) ) {
                $posts_in_ex_tags_sql = " AND tt.taxonomy = 'post_tag' AND tt.term_id NOT IN (" . implode($excluded_tags, ',') . ')';
            }
        }
    }

    $adjacent = $previous ? 'previous' : 'next';
    $op = $previous ? '<' : '>';
    $order = $previous ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';

    $join  = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_join", $join, $in_same_tag, $excluded_tags );
    $where = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_where", $wpdb->prepare("WHERE p.post_date $op %s AND p.post_type = %s AND p.post_status = 'publish' $posts_in_ex_tags_sql", $current_post_date, $post->post_type), $in_same_tag, $excluded_tags );
    $sort  = apply_filters( "get_{$adjacent}_post_sort", "ORDER BY p.post_date $order LIMIT 1" );

    $query = "SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts AS p $join $where $sort";
    $query_key = 'adjacent_post_' . md5($query);
    $result = wp_cache_get($query_key, 'counts');
    if ( false !== $result )
        return $result;

    $result = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT p.* FROM $wpdb->posts AS p $join $where $sort");
    if ( null === $result )
        $result = '';

    wp_cache_set($query_key, $result, 'counts');
    return $result;
}
```