# Get Adjacent Post By Tag

Tags: tags, next-post-link, previous-post-link

In this answer -- [How to Get Next or Previous Post in a Specific Tag?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14150/how-to-get-next-or-previous-post-in-a-specific-tag) -- a working function is provided to generate "next/prev" links by tag rather than category.

How could one make this so that you can specify exactly which tag to generate next/previous links for? As it is, it appears to only allow you to *exclude* tags from consideration. As posts tend to have many tags, it's seems unreliable (with the function as-is) to reply on the in_same_tag option.

Answer (score 0):

I would check out the [Ambrosite Next/Previous Post Link Plus](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ambrosite-nextprevious-post-link-plus/) plugin which gives you a lot of arguments to pass to the "improved" next/prev link functions made by the plugin. I recently needed this type of functionality and this plugin worked great.

With the plugin, you get to do [stuff like this](http://www.ambrosite.com/plugins/next-previous-post-link-plus-for-wordpress):

```
<?php next_post_link_plus( array('in_cats' => '3,5') ); ?>
```